# Angular4: Recovering one-way data binding value on input after resetting the form

Tags: angular

I have a form like (simplified version):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">

  <!-- other inputs without data binding -->

  <input
    type="text"
    id="item-input"
    [ngModel]="myService.getCurrentItem().name"
    name="item"
    #item="ngModel">

   <!-- other inputs without data binding -->

    <button
      (click)="onClearForm(f)">
      New
    </button>

</form>
```

and on the component:

```
  ...

  onClearForm(form: NgForm){
    form.reset();
  }

  ...
```

So, after resetting the form, the input get effectively gets cleared. How do I get back the value from the data binding just after resetting?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just grab the value before resetting the form...?

```
@ViewChild('item') item: string;

lastItem: string;

onClearForm(form: NgForm){
    this.lastItem = this.item;
    form.reset();
}
```

A couple things: I wouldn't data-bind a function call to a form control. Angular ends up calling these constantly behind the scenes; it can get pretty ugly and it's not performant.

It's probably better to just two-way data bind it; that's kind of what you're doing with the exported `item` template variable, but much more cleanly:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="item-input"
  [(ngModel)]="myItem"
  name="item">
```

in component:

```
export class SomeComponent({

    myItem: string = ''; // or whatever default value you want

    constructor(public myService: MyService) {
      this.myItem = myService.getCurrentItem().name;
    }


    onClearForm(form: NgForm){
      let theValue = this.myItem;
      form.reset();
      console.log(`I still have myItem!: ${theValue});
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I do need bind to a function of a service despite the penalties because this value can be edited from a parallel component shown at the same time.